# How to position brace label?

Tags: braces

I want this layout but I can't control the placement of s1, s2 and s3.
How do I achieve this. My MWE follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (Origin)   at (0,0);
    \coordinate (XAxisMin) at (-2.0,0);
    \coordinate (XAxisMax) at (2.0,0);
    \coordinate (YAxisMin) at (0,-2.2);
    \coordinate (YAxisMax) at (0,2.2);
    \draw  (XAxisMin) -- (XAxisMax);
    \draw  (YAxisMin) -- (YAxisMax);
    \coordinate (P1) at (-2,-2);
    \coordinate (P2) at (-1,-1.74);
    \coordinate (P3) at (0.82,0);
    \coordinate (P4) at (2,2);
    \draw [thick,green] (P1) -- (P2) -- (P3) -- (P4);
    \draw (P1) node[circle,fill,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=2pt,label=above:$p_1$](){};
    \draw (P2) node[circle,fill,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=2pt,label=above:$p_2$](){};
    \draw (P3) node[circle,fill,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=2pt,label=above left:$p_3$](){};
    \draw (P4) node[circle,fill,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=2pt,label=above left:$p_4$](){};
    \draw[red,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=10pt},decorate](P1) -- node[below=10pt] {$s_1$}(P2);
    \draw[red,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=10pt},decorate](P2) -- node[right=16pt] {$s_2$}(P3);
    \draw[red,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=10pt},decorate](P3) -- node[right=16pt] {$s_3$}(P4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you agree, that braces labels is oriented with brace (what is some have expected to be), tha solution is relative simple. Use `\draw[brace ...] (Pi) -- node[sloped,below=12pt] {Si} (Pj);`

Complete code, in which I take liberty to make it shorter (as possible), is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, 
              minimum size=1mm, inner sep=2pt,
              node contents = {},
              label=120:#1}, %< --- changed
brc/.style = {red,
              decoration={brace,mirror,raise=10pt},
              decorate}
                    ]
    \coordinate (Origin)   at (0,0);
    \coordinate (XAxisMin) at (-2.0,0);
    \coordinate (XAxisMax) at (2.0,0);
    \coordinate (YAxisMin) at (0,-2.2);
    \coordinate (YAxisMax) at (0,2.2);
\draw  (XAxisMin) -- (XAxisMax);
\draw  (YAxisMin) -- (YAxisMax);
    \coordinate (P1) at (-2,-2);
    \coordinate (P2) at (-1,-1.74);
    \coordinate (P3) at (0.82,0);
    \coordinate (P4) at (2,2);
\draw   (P1) node[dot=$p_1$] --
        (P2) node[dot=$p_2$] --
        (P3) node[dot=$p_3$] --
        (P4) node[dot=$p_4$];
\draw[brc](P1) -- node[sloped,below=12pt] {$s_1$} (P2);
\draw[brc](P2) -- node[sloped,below=12pt] {$s_2$}(P3);
\draw[brc](P3) -- node[sloped,below=12pt] {$s_3$}(P4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Above code generate the following graph:

[image]

**Edit:**
Only slightly improved position of node labels ...

Answer (score 5):

A bit tedious, but you can modify the `pos` and the distance. The nodes are positioned relative to the path between the points, not on the shifted path along the brace. So when you place a node directly below the mid point of the path between `P1` and `P2`, it ends up to the left of the middle of the brace, because of the angle of the line.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (Origin)   at (0,0);
    \coordinate (XAxisMin) at (-2.0,0);
    \coordinate (XAxisMax) at (2.0,0);
    \coordinate (YAxisMin) at (0,-2.2);
    \coordinate (YAxisMax) at (0,2.2);
    \draw  (XAxisMin) -- (XAxisMax);
    \draw  (YAxisMin) -- (YAxisMax);
    \coordinate (P1) at (-2,-2);
    \coordinate (P2) at (-1,-1.74);
    \coordinate (P3) at (0.82,0);
    \coordinate (P4) at (2,2);
    \draw [thick,green] (P1) -- (P2) -- (P3) -- (P4);
    \draw (P1) node[circle,fill,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=2pt,label=above:$p_1$](){};
    \draw (P2) node[circle,fill,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=2pt,label=above:$p_2$](){};
    \draw (P3) node[circle,fill,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=2pt,label=above left:$p_3$](){};
    \draw (P4) node[circle,fill,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=2pt,label=above left:$p_4$](){};
    \draw[red,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=10pt},decorate](P1) -- node[below=12pt,pos=0.7] {$s_1$} (P2);
    \draw[red,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=10pt},decorate](P2) -- node[right=20pt,pos=0.25] {$s_2$} (P3);
    \draw[red,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=10pt},decorate](P3) -- node[right=15pt,pos=0.35] {$s_3$} (P4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could set a node `S1` midway along the brace between `P1` and `P2`. Then, using the `calc` library, you find the midpoint `M1` between points `P1` and `P2`. Lastly, you place the brace label in a node some distance beyond the path from `M1` to `S1`. Repeat for the other braces.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, 
              minimum size=1mm, inner sep=2pt,
              node contents = {},
              label=above:#1},
brc/.style = {red,
              decoration={brace,mirror,raise=10pt},
              decorate}
                    ]
    \coordinate (Origin)   at (0,0);
    \coordinate (XAxisMin) at (-2.0,0);
    \coordinate (XAxisMax) at (2.0,0);
    \coordinate (YAxisMin) at (0,-2.2);
    \coordinate (YAxisMax) at (0,2.2);
\draw  (XAxisMin) -- (XAxisMax);
\draw  (YAxisMin) -- (YAxisMax);
    \coordinate (P1) at (-2,-2);
    \coordinate (P2) at (-1,-1.74);
    \coordinate (P3) at (0.82,0);
    \coordinate (P4) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (M1) at ($(P1)!0.5!(P2)$);
    \coordinate (M2) at ($(P2)!0.5!(P3)$);
    \coordinate (M3) at ($(P3)!0.5!(P4)$);
\draw [thick,green] (P1) -- (P2) -- (P3) -- (P4);
    \draw (P1) node[circle,fill,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=2pt,label=above:$p_1$](){};
    \draw (P2) node[circle,fill,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=2pt,label=above:$p_2$](){};
    \draw (P3) node[circle,fill,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=2pt,label=above left:$p_3$](){};
    \draw (P4) node[circle,fill,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=2pt,label=above left:$p_4$](){};\draw[brc](P1) -- node(S1)[sloped,below=12pt] {} (P2);
\draw[brc](P2) -- node(S2)[sloped,below=12pt] {}(P3);
\draw[brc](P3) -- node(S3)[sloped,below=12pt] {}(P4);
\path[red] (M1) to ($(M1)!1.2!(S1)$) node{$s_1$};
\path[red] (M2) to ($(M2)!1.2!(S2)$) node{$s_2$};
\path[red] (M3) to ($(M3)!1.2!(S3)$) node{$s_3$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]