# How to improve poorly rendered braces around TikZ figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, braces, rendering

Trying with TikZ to have a figure surrounded by braces above and below, the result is quite ugly: braces as well as node besides look poorly rendered, as it there was a problem in their rasterization.

[image: rasterized braces]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{intcalc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nlength}{12}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mlength}{4}
    \foreach \i in {-1,...,\nlength} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\end}{\i + 1.2};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mid}{\i + 0.6};
        \newcommand\drawColor{black}
        \newcommand\fillColor{white}
        \newcommand\elementClass{B}
        \ifthenelse
            {\equal{\intcalcMod{\i}{\nlength}}{0}}
            {%
                \renewcommand\drawColor{red!80!white}
                \renewcommand\fillColor{red!80!white}
                \renewcommand\elementClass{I}
            }%
            {\ifthenelse%
                {\equal{\intcalcMod{\i}{\mlength}}{0}}
                {
                    \renewcommand\drawColor{red!40!white}
                    \renewcommand\fillColor{red!40!white}
                    \renewcommand\elementClass{P}
                }{}%
            }
        \draw[\drawColor,fill=\fillColor] (\i, 0) -- (\end, 1) -- (\end, -1) -- (\i, -2) -- (\i, 0);
        \node at (\mid, -0.6) {\elementClass};
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt, raise=5pt}] (0.6, 1) -- (\nlength, 1) node [rectangle, draw=black, midway, yshift=1cm, font=\small] {$N = \nlength$};
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt, raise=5pt, mirror}] (0.6, -2) -- (\mlength, -2) node [rectangle, draw=black, midway, yshift=-1cm, font=\small] {$M = \mlength$};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I've made lots of other figures with the same configuration without any problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome!

1. As pointed out in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372787/194703), there is the `calligraphic brace` specifically for that.
2. **Never** call a macro `\end` as done in `\pgfmathsetmacro{\end}{\i + 1.2};`. You were very lucky that your code worked (because you had this in the loop).  (The `;` are superfluous, too.) In particular, if the macro is not needed, as Ti*k*Z is parsing its expression.
3. You draw the brace many times because it is in the loop. Not needed. I suspect that part of the viewer-dependent ugliness comes from adding the brace so many times.
4. You do not need the `ifthen` nor `intcalc` packages. On the long run you will encounter difficulties if you continue this practice.
5. You can use the `3d` library to project the texts on the planes.

Here is the revised code with a calligraphic brace.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nlength}{12}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mlength}{4}
    \foreach \i in {-1,...,\nlength} {
        \newcommand\drawColor{black}
        \newcommand\fillColor{white}
        \newcommand\elementClass{B}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{Mod(\i,\nlength)}
        \ifnum\itest=0
                \renewcommand\drawColor{red!80!white}
                \renewcommand\fillColor{red!80!white}
                \renewcommand\elementClass{I}
        \else
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\jtest}{Mod(\i,\mlength)}
            \ifnum\jtest=0
                    \renewcommand\drawColor{red!40!white}
                    \renewcommand\fillColor{red!40!white}
                    \renewcommand\elementClass{P}
            \fi
        \fi         
        \begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=\i]
        \draw[\drawColor,fill=\fillColor] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
        \path (0,0) node[transform shape,xscale=-1] {\elementClass};
        \end{scope}
    }
    \draw[decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=10pt,
        raise=5pt},line width=1pt] (0, 1.4) -- (\nlength-0.6, 1.4) node [rectangle, draw=black, midway, yshift=1cm, font=\small] {$N = \nlength$};
    \draw[decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=10pt,
        raise=5pt, mirror},line width=1pt] (0, -1.4) -- (\mlength-0.6, -1.4) node [rectangle,
        draw=black, midway, yshift=-1cm, font=\small] {$M = \mlength$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution to the question and the other ones I hadn't seen, thanks a lot!

Comment: @bmrs You're welcome!