# Lucida: Make large braces the same style as small braces

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, braces, lucida

I noticed the problem with the `cases` environment, but it is due to using braces that are bigger than `\Bigg`.

[image]

How can I make (1) to be the same style as (2)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[]{LucidaBrightMathOT.otf}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^m & \text{if \(i \neq j\)} \\
    1                   & \text{if \(i = j\)}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    \sum_{i=1}^m & \text{if \(i \neq j\)} \\
    1            & \text{if \(i = j\)}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: luatex or xetex? It is a choice of the font designer so can't be controlled from tex, you could use the lua virtual font feature to remove the designed { and move directly to the form made from extension pieces. Or you could use a very small font size, then they would both be straight, but thin

Comment: a font has a fixed number of designed `{` then switches to an extension form that has to be straight as it is made up of segments. Or you can use tikz to draw a `{` and not use a font (answers on this site somewhere)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372776/appealing-braces-in-tikz

Comment: I use lualatex.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution you can use braces from another math font, for example Latin Modern Math. `unicode-math` allows loading ranges of math characters from different fonts. The following code uses braces from Latin Modern Math while all the other symbols are taken from STIX Two Math (I don't have Lucida to use in the example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range={"007B,"007D}]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={}]
\begin{document}
\[
\qquad
\left\{
  \begin{matrix}
    1&0\\
    0&1
  \end{matrix}
\right\}
\qquad
\left\{
  \begin{matrix}
    1&0&0\\
    0&1&0\\
    0&0&1
  \end{matrix}
\right\}
\qquad
\left\{
  \begin{matrix}
    1&0&0&0\\
    0&1&0&0\\
    0&0&1&0\\
    0&0&0&1
  \end{matrix}
\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

and the result without font substitution would be:
[image]

Note that every use of `\setmathfont` overwrites the math font metrics, so in order to get the correct one I had to add `\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={}]` after replacing braces.